# TypeError: argument of type 'SubcommandObject' is not iterable

Tags: python, discord.py

When I try to do :

```py
@slash.subcommand(name='lot', base='present', subcommand_group='get')
async def get_lot(ctx):
    # some code
```

on this specific command I have this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python\bot-katsu\bot-katsu\bot.py", line 747, in <module>
    async def _get_present_lot(ctx):
  File "C:\Users\jejou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\client.py", line 641, in wrapper
    obj = self.add_subcommand(cmd, base, subcommand_group, name, description, base_description, subcommand_group_description, guild_ids, options, connector)
  File "C:\Users\jejou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\client.py", line 497, in add_subcommand
    if name in self.subcommands[base][subcommand_group]:
TypeError: argument of type 'SubcommandObject' is not iterable
```

So someone can help me?

Comment: The function definition you've shown us doesn't match what's in the error message. Are you showing us the correct function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, It's because I have two command and one has "get" at name and this command has it at subcommand_group